# Using AdMob Singleton in Swift - Valid Impressions?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, admob

Thanks for reading.

I want to verify with others that the way I am loading a single advertisement throughout my whole app is correct. The ad is set to refresh itself every 30 seconds from the server side.

I want as many impressions as I can possibly get, valid impressions (that means for 30 seconds or until the ad refreshes on the server side). Users may not be on a particular screen of my app for 30 seconds, so I need the ad to still be valid on the next screen and the impression counted. The same ad, on different screens, depending on where the user is. That is why I am using a singleton.

I also have a question with GADRequest -- everytime I call GADRequest for my ad, does that start a new impression? If so, I don't want it to be called but only once, what is the best method to implement that correctly?

Am I doing this correctly and maximizing accuracy and profit?

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class SingletonAd: GADBannerView {
    static let singletonAd = SingletonAd()

    init() {
        super.init(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

        self.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-*****"
        self.alpha = 0
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Inside of an example ViewController:

```
let banner = SingletonAd.singletonAd

banner.rootViewController = self
banner.delegate = self
let req : GADRequest = GADRequest()
banner.loadRequest(req)
banner.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height -  banner.frame.size.height, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height)
self.view.addSubview(banner)

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.banner.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        let req : GADRequest = GADRequest()
        banner.loadRequest(req)
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Have you made any progress determining if your code is correct?

Comment: This helped me get started : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/QLUsGH0FyCk

Comment: It's basically the same as my code so yes in a sense the code is "correct." However I need to know whether or not a new impression is created and the cycle starts over when on a new view controller by calling the GADrequest.

Comment: Thanks for link so I could verify my code, that I do appreciate.